# Click through a series of divs

Tags: css, href, lightbox

I have a similar setup to the code below where a gallery type link opens up a div with a dark background and an enlarged image (like this: https://codepen.io/ongtiffany/pen/BoOeQV).

What I want to do is link these lightbox div's to one another (with left and right arrows) so that you can close the currently open div and open the correct adjacent div, effectively switching between the enlarged images.

```
<div class="lightbox" id="1">
    <div class ="lightbox_content">Some stuff here.</div>
    <a href="#lightbox_2"><div class ="lightbox_r">&rarr;</div></a>
</div>

<div class="lightbox" id="1">
    <a href="#lightbox_1"><div class ="lightbox_l">&larr;</div></a>
    <div class="lightbox_content">Some stuff here.</div>
    <a href="#lightbox_3"><div class="lightbox_r">&rarr;</div></a>
</div>

<div class="lightbox" id="3">
    <a href="#lightbox_2"><div class ="lightbox_l">&larr;</div></a>
    <div class="lightbox_content">Some stuff here.</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be amazing - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Try using some of specialized "lightbox" libraries. Almost all of them have support for linking multiple images into series and navigating using arrows or some buttons.

- http://photoswipe.com/ (my personal favorite)
- http://fancybox.net/
- http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
- http://highslide.com/
- almost everything you can google with "lightbox"

Comment: Great suggestion, but there's a lot of customization I need to build into each div. I think I would struggle more understanding and editing one of these. It's actually almost complete - I just need to work out this next/previous arrows thing.

Comment: Many lighbox libraries load inline content.